# MVC data security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, model-view-controller, ssl, encryption

I am a beginner of MVC. I am now curious about the data security.
I don't know if I have a wrong concept.

Here is the scenario:
I have a view to ask users to input some data. (client-side)
When the data passes back to the controller (server-side), can the eavesdropper intercept the data inputted by the users? (i.e. is the data encrypted?)

If the data is not encrypted, how can I make the data secure?
I think SSL (https) may be an option. But what else can I do if I not to use SSL?
Is asymmetric encryption an option here?
(I think encryption on view is not appropriate...but i cannot think a better option)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC doesn't encrypt your traffic. If you're trying to secure your website, SSL is your best option.